# Is it possible to use the select-size-attribute in combination with bootstrap-select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-select

... and if so, how? I have a select element in combination with a size-attribute, i.e.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" size="5">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to add some further information to the options - [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) could do the job, but it ignores the select-size-attribute/throws errors:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select size="5" class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true">
  <option data-subtext="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-subtext="Barbecue">Barbecue</option>
  <option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-subtext="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-subtext="Barbecue">Barbecue</option>
  <option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-subtext="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-subtext="Barbecue">Barbecue</option>
  <option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: I forgot to say that I know the 'data-size' attribute - of course this works, but I still have a dropdown. What I achieve is to have a box like in my first example but with 'styled' option elements like in the second one.

If the job could not be done with bootstrap-select, alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multiselect to get a similar result.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<select class="custom-select form-control" multiple>
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: pls see my updated question; unfortunately the 'data-show-subtext' attribute and the 'data-subtext'-attributes are ignored if I add them to your example

Comment: @Rorschach umm, yes, they get ignored. Can't seem to find a solution right away to show it as subtext. From the top of my head I'm thinking of showing a label under the select to show a description whenever the selected option changes, maybe that's something you can look into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-size instead of size or you can add this.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.10/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select size="5" class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true">
<option data-subtext="Mustard">Mustard</option>
<option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option data-subtext="Barbecue">Barbecue</option>
<option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option data-subtext="Mustard">Mustard</option>
<option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option data-subtext="Barbecue">Barbecue</option>
<option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option data-subtext="Mustard">Mustard</option>
<option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option data-subtext="Barbecue">Barbecue</option>
<option data-subtext="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
```

```
<script>
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
```

Comment: pls see my edit; your second suggestion doesn't work - I receive the same erros.